# Vbs msgbox. How do I create custom buttons?

Tags: vbscript

Ok, I'm trying to make a small rpg as a small project in vbs. What I'm after is a msgbox with 5 buttons: attack, skils, magic, run, help.

My knowledge of vbscript is quite minimal, so you may need to explain.

Comment: "attack, skils, magic, run, help" -- "take" is missing.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot easily do that with VBScript. (Wouldn't it be nice if you could do something like `choice = MsgBox("Please select my next action", array("attack", "skills", "magic", "run", "take", "help"))`).

But you can do the good old create-an-IE-instance-with-choices-hack. You can find examples and explanations on [The Scripting Guys' Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/07/19/how-can-i-create-a-custom-dialog-box.aspx) or on the [site of Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_buttons.php).

Ninja edit: While you are looking at blending HTML code with VBScript, you should checkout [this article about HTA's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx). I think this is just what you are looking for if you want to fiddle around with VBScript and need a GUI to make it interactive.