# VBS How to make a Custom Option Button?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I would like to create a VB script that will have 3 buttons: A Day, B Day as C Day, and then have each button launch a batch file. I know how to make preset buttons (Yes, No, Abort, Retry etc.), but not custom. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vbs msgbox. How do I create custom buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677345/vbs-msgbox-how-do-i-create-custom-buttons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you stick to VBScript only, you will not be able to create custom buttons. You can review the Function summary for [MsgBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

[InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) might give you the A, B, C options you're looking for but it would require the user to enter the letter and hit enter.

Otherwise, you can do a little trickery using IE as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/07/19/how-can-i-create-a-custom-dialog-box.aspx) and [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_buttons.php).